# Sketch a line on an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to draw a line after I load the image.
The line is a drawn manually.
Once I try to upload an image and draw something on an it, it stops working.
Can someone please tell me how can I overlap the id of the image and the id of the drawing box.

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ghostoy/wTmFE/1/) to see the demo of the drawing

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
<div id="coord"></div>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just have the canvas inside another div and use an image as the div's background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have the canvas inside a div and change the div's background image

```
<div style="background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Mouse_line_drawing.jpg');width:auto;height:auto;display:inline-block;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="coord"></div>
```

Comment: One small question, would this wrok if I wanted to draw on a video ?

Comment: Not too sure about that, since the video would have the controls and the pause button. And then you'd also have the problem because you can't have a video as a background image, but you can always try it out